# How to create a "detail panel" in Cytoscape?

Tags: cytoscape

I'm generating networks and importing them into Cytoscape using [cyREST](http://apps.cytoscape.org/apps/cyrest).

I have a lot of extra information available about each node, more than can be fit into node labels.  I would like the user to be able to click on a node and bring up a detail panel with this additional info.   Is there any feature of Cytoscape, or an existing plugin that can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way from within CyREST to do that, although you could encode that information in a single text column and then use the 'tooltip' visual property to provide a way for a user to get the information on a mouseover.  Beyond that, you would need to provide an app to integrate with your CyREST application.  Several apps do exactly what you are describing (e.g. look at StringApp for an example)

-- scooter